# Laravel 6 view include from sub directory not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I need to include two blade files `navbar` & `sidebar` (located in `views/layouts/partials`) in another blade template named `admin.blade.php` (located in views/layouts). So in `admin.blade.php`. I wrote

```
<div class="page-body">
    @include('partials.sidebar')
    <div class="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="page-content-wrapper-inner">
            <div class="content-viewport">
                @include('partials.content')
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

it gives me this error:

> Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewExceptionView [partials.navbar] not
>   found.

Can you help me? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put `layouts` as part of the path, so your template code should be like below:

```
div class="page-body">
    @include('layouts.partials.sidebar')
    <div class="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="page-content-wrapper-inner">
            <div class="content-viewport">
                @include('layouts.partials.content')
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```